# Trying to plot a specific interaction created within lavaan in R

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I have constructed an additive moderation model within lavaan in R and I am trying to plot a specific interaction that stems from the model. I am struggling with how to plot the interaction as most of the methods that do that such as the `interactions` package or `probemod` do not work with lavaan objects. The following is the code for the model and the specific interaction I need to plot is "PGC7.AVG:I3.AVG".

```
dataf$SIIAVG <- scale(dataf$SIIAVG, scale = F)
dataf$PGC7.AVG <- scale(dataf$PGC7.AVG, scale = F)
dataf$I3.AVG <- scale(dataf$I3.AVG, scale = F)
INT2.mod <- '
Headspace_duration36to180_Sqrt ~ CAA.AVG + BSC.AVG.NEW + SN3.1.DESnorms + SN3.AVG.INJnorms + SIIAVG +      PGC7.AVG + I3.AVG + SIIAVG:I3.AVG + PGC7.AVG:I3.AVG + Headspace_Count35_Sqrt + Headspace_Duration35_Sqrt
Headspace_Count36to180_Sqrt ~ CAA.AVG + BSC.AVG.NEW + SN3.1.DESnorms + SN3.AVG.INJnorms + PGC7.AVG + I3.AVG + SIIAVG:I3.AVG + PGC7.AVG:I3.AVG + Headspace_Count35_Sqrt + Headspace_Duration35_Sqrt
Headspace_Count35_Sqrt ~ CAA.AVG + BSC.AVG.NEW + SN3.1.DESnorms + SN3.AVG.INJnorms + PGC7.AVG + I3.AVG + SIIAVG:I3.AVG + PGC7.AVG:I3.AVG
Headspace_Duration35_Sqrt ~ CAA.AVG + BSC.AVG.NEW + SN3.1.DESnorms + SN3.AVG.INJnorms + PGC7.AVG + I3.AVG + SIIAVG:I3.AVG + PGC7.AVG:I3.AVG
I3.AVG ~ CAA.AVG + BSC.AVG.NEW + SN3.1.DESnorms + SN3.AVG.INJnorms 
#Covariances
CAA.AVG ~~ BSC.AVG.NEW
CAA.AVG ~~ SN3.1.DESnorms
CAA.AVG ~~ SN3.AVG.INJnorms
BSC.AVG.NEW ~~ SN3.1.DESnorms
BSC.AVG.NEW ~~ SN3.AVG.INJnorms
SN3.1.DESnorms ~~ SN3.AVG.INJnorms
Headspace_duration36to180_Sqrt ~~ Headspace_Count36to180_Sqrt
Headspace_Count35_Sqrt ~~ Headspace_Duration35_Sqrt
'

INT2.out <- sem(INT2.mod, data=dataf, fixed.x = F)
```

I tried the following code:

```
sd(dataf$PGC7.AVG)
BYrange <- range(dataf$I3.AVG, na.rm = TRUE)
em.mass <- emmeans(INT2.out, specs = ~ I3.AVG | PGC7.AVG, 
                   at = list(PGC7.AVG = -0.9397057:0.9397057, I3.AVG = BYrange),
                   # because SEMs can have multiple DVs:
                   lavaan.DV = "Headspace_duration36to180_Sqrt", data = dataf)
```

But I got the following error:

```
# Error in EETA[, ov.x.dummy.lv.idx] <- eXo : replacement has length zero
```

Comment: Have you installed the current development version of semTools from GitHub?  There were some recent changes that had to do with missing data and variable ordering, not sure if relevant for your data.  Also, the colon operator may not be doing what you expect.  Try `PGC7.AVG = c(-0.9397057, 0.9397057)`.  And does it make sense to compare the min/max of `I3.AVG` instead of a 1-unit increase? (`I3.AVG = 1:0`)  Finally, `scale()` returns a matrix, so extract the first column/vector or just mean-center manually; it can have strange consequences to store a matrix in a `data.frame`, which is a `list`

Comment: Dear Terrence, thank you for your answer.

I am afraid that after including all of your suggestions I am still receiving the exact same error. Could it be because the variables are continious? 

Best wishes,
Vlad

Comment: Try editing your post to include a reproducible example, including your updated syntax and enough (real or fake) data for us to reproduce the error.